# lxde shutdown icon not working

Tags: shutdown

I have Ubuntu installed with LXDE as the desktop.
The red shutdown tray icon is unresponsive, as is the 
logout item in the main menu.
I have everything up to date. 
Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when I updated to 16.04. Somehow the package lxsession-logout wasn't installed, so after sudo apt-get install lxsession-logout the menu and icon for the logout worked

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. I had the same issue after update to 16.04 :)